# How to generate a non-growing (int) random array c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I'm trying to make a Integer (int) array with random numbers NOT growing.
For example: 3 10 5 9 20
But NOT: 3 5 9 10 20 (because they just grow)

I'm using Random class with this code (but I always get a growing list like in the second example):

```
int[] array1 = new int[5];
Random random_istance = new Random();
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 array1[i] = random.Next(0,999999);
}
```

I also tried with a code like (I know it is horrible programming) :

```
int[] array1 = new int[5];
Random random_istance = new Random();
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 random = new Random(x-y*z); // re-instantation
 array1[i] = random.Next(0,999999);    // x,y and z are variable defined outside
}
```

(*) My final goal is to get an array of random int between 0 and 999999 but some are to not to be in a sequence (because later I'm going to apply an algorithm to order the array and would not make sense to order a already-ordered array).

Moreover I have to create ANOTHER array with elements just DECREASING (so one random array , and one decreasing array).

Any idea how to salve at least first problem (*)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: code posted doesn't compile. Nor when fixed(minor naming) does it give me the problem you are describing

Comment: To create decreasing array, just create an array with random values and sort id descending.

Comment: I assume that it was simple random that they were growing with your first approach(when compiling), hence thzat should work.

Comment: Growing can still be random. If you apply limitation to order you are affecting randomness.

Comment: If you're testing your sorting algoritm you can just use list of decreasing sequance like 5,4,3,2,1. It doesnt matter for such algorithms if there are realy random numbers.

Comment: @Piotr is mandatory for the project I'm making to have random generation.

Comment: @dragonmnl I mean exactly what I've written. Decreasing array is just an array sorted descending. You may be confused by the typo: _id_ == _it_. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to ensure that your array is not sorted from low to high is by ordering it randomly when you detect its ordered based on the value, something like:

```
        // while the array is sorted
        var sortedCopy = array1.ToList();
        sortedCopy.Sort();
        while (array1.SequenceEqual(sortedCopy))
        {
            Array.Sort(array1, new Comparison<int>((left, right) => random.Next(-1, 1)));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle array after generating:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {
                array1 = array1.OrderBy(c => random_istance.Next()).ToArray();
            }
```

Comment: it is exactly as good as not shuffling it, because the array can 'suddenly' end up sorted.

Comment: Thank you for help.But this doesn't work (compile,but the order is the same)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this would be a good solution, but you may try this:

1. Create random array with desired size.
2. Sort this array ascending.
3. Swap random elements `i` times, where `i` is a random number > 0.

To get decreasing numbers, create random array and just sort it descending.

---

**Edit** Of course it is possible, that you will end up with unchanged sequention if `i` is even. I think it is enough to swap elements `i` times, where `i` is greater than 0 and odd.